# Hibernate Entity many to one как использовать в сервлете?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring, hibernate, java

Использую Hibernate4, Spring mvc4, maven, tomcat7.

Есть две таблицы: Категории и Проекты. Отношение Категории к Проектам = один-ко-многим, по ключу: `ID_CATEGORY`.

Хочу показать список проектов, которые содержатся в конкретной Категории через `@Controller`, но не знаю, как их вызвать.

Сейчас вывожу Проекты конкретной Категории в Контроллере таким образом:

```
List<Project> projects = projectService.findAllProjects(idCategory);

    @Entity
@Table(name="CATEGORIES", uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "ID_CATEGORY")})
public class Category {

    public Category() {
    }

    public Category(int idCategory) {
        this.idCategory = idCategory;
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID_CATEGORY", unique = true, nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int idCategory;

    @Size(min=3, max=50)
    @Column(name = "NAME", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Project> projects;

    public List<Project> getProjects() {
        return this.projects;
    }

    public void setProjects(List<Project> projects) {
        this.projects = projects;
    }

    public int getIdCategory() {
        return idCategory;
    }

    public void setIdCategory(int idCategory) {
        this.idCategory = idCategory;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (!(obj instanceof Category))
            return false;
        Category other = (Category) obj;
        if (idCategory != other.idCategory)
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Category [id=" + idCategory + ", name=" + name + "]";
    }
}

    @Entity
@Table(name = "PROJECTS")
public class Project {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID_PROJECT")
    private int idProject;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "ID_CATEGORY")
    private String idCategory;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 3, max = 50)
    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 15, max = 250)
    @Column(name = "SHORT_DESCRIPTION")
    private String shortDescription;

    @Size(min = 30, max = 500)
    @Column(name = "FULL_DESCRIPTION")
    private String fullDescription;

    @Column(name = "FOTO")
    private String foto;

    @Column(name = "LINK")
    private String link;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "HOW_MUCH_NEEDED")
    private int howMuchNeeded;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "HOW_MUCH_COLLECTED")
    private int howMuchCollected;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "HOW_MUCH_REMAINING")
    private int howMuchRemaining;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalDate")
    @Column(name = "DATE_CLOSE")
    private LocalDate dateClose;

    @Column(name = "FAQ")
    private ArrayList<String> faq;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_CATEGORY", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Category category;

    public Category getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(Category category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getFaq() {
        return faq;
    }

    public void setFaq(ArrayList<String> faq) {
        this.faq = faq;
    }

    public int getIdProject() {
        return idProject;
    }

    public void setIdProject(int idProject) {
        this.idProject = idProject;
    }

    public String getIdCategory() {
        return idCategory;
    }

    public void setIdCategory(String idCategory) {
        this.idCategory = idCategory;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getShortDescription() {
        return shortDescription;
    }

    public void setShortDescription(String shortDescription) {
        this.shortDescription = shortDescription;
    }

    public String getFullDescription() {
        return fullDescription;
    }

    public void setFullDescription(String fullDescription) {
        this.fullDescription = fullDescription;
    }

    public String getFoto() {
        return foto;
    }

    public void setFoto(String foto) {
        this.foto = foto;
    }

    public String getLink() {
        return link;
    }

    public void setLink(String link) {
        this.link = link;
    }

    public int getHowMuchNeeded() {
        return howMuchNeeded;
    }

    public void setHowMuchNeeded(int howMuchNeeded) {
        this.howMuchNeeded = howMuchNeeded;
    }

    public int getHowMuchCollected() {
        return howMuchCollected;
    }

    public void setHowMuchCollected(int howMuchCollected) {
        this.howMuchCollected = howMuchCollected;
    }

    public int getHowMuchRemaining() {
        return howMuchRemaining;
    }

    public void setHowMuchRemaining(int howMuchRemaining) {
        this.howMuchRemaining = howMuchRemaining;
    }

    public LocalDate getDateClose() {
        return dateClose;
    }

    public void setDateClose(LocalDate dateClose) {
        this.dateClose = dateClose;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (!(obj instanceof Project))
            return false;
        Project other = (Project) obj;
        if (idProject != other.idProject)
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Project [idProject=" + idProject + "idCategory=" + idCategory + ", name=" + name + ", dateClose="
                + dateClose + "]";
    }

}

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class AppController {

    @Autowired
    CategoryService categoryService;

    @Autowired
    ProjectService projectService;

    @RequestMapping(value = { "/", "/categories" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String listCategories(ModelMap model) {
        List<Category> categories = categoryService.findAllCategories();

        model.addAttribute("categories", categories);
        return "categories";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = { "/projects" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String listProjects(HttpServletRequest req, ModelMap model) {
        int idCategory = Integer.valueOf(req.getParameter("category"));

        List<Project> projects = projectService.findAllProjects(idCategory);
        model.addAttribute("projects", projects);
        model.addAttribute("category", idCategory);
        return "projects";
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

скорее всего, необходимо указать какое поле мапить для связи. к примеру так:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "ID_CATEGORY")
private List<Project> projects;
```